# Limit element's height based on parent's max-height

Tags: html, css

My Code looks like this (Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/2x3h0ne7/):

```css
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.outer {
  max-height:50%;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">Text in here...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `.inner` has text in it and the `.outer` will expand it's height according to `.inner` height.

If `.inner` height is smaller than `.outer` height (50% of `.wrapper`) then `.outer` will have the same height as `.inner`.

If `.inner` height is larger than 50% of `.wrapper` then `.outer` height will be 50% of `.wrapper` but `.inner` will continue to grow and overflow `.outer`.

Is it possible to limit `.inner` height to `.outer` `max-height`?

I'm looking for a CSS only approach!

Comment: You could assign `overflow: hidden;` to `.outer`. But you may need another wrapper to get the padding right.

Comment: @lupz That will limit the 'visual' `height` of `.inner`, not the actual `height`. So it has no use to me.

Comment: @xpy https://jsfiddle.net/Jinukurian7/2x3h0ne7/3/ Check this. I think there is no css method for your issue.

Comment: @JinuKurian Doesn't seem to work on my chrome, is it for canary?

Comment: @xpy No. Its working in my Chrome47.

Comment: @JinuKurian It is working, but `-webkit-line-clamp` value is fixed and won't work for varying `.outer` heights.